# How can you disable the Google "Did you just sign in?" notification

Tags: google-account, google

Title sums it up. I use my Google account on many devices. Including virtual machines and other items that may get reset and have to be logged in again frequently. It is annoying having to constantly swipe away this notification on multiple devices (5+) around the house when I already use two step verification and extremely secure passwords plus I get the email notification.
How can I disable this notification from coming back again?

Answer (score 3):

To remove:

Settings -> Apps -> Google Play Services -> Notifications -> Block all

That should remove those notifications now.

Source [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/582140-annoying-sign-notification-won-t-go-away.html)

Comment: I don't want to disable all notifications from "Google Play Services", just the sign-in prompt. Do you know which notification category I should disable?